# Uni question regarding overriding and shadowing in java

Tags: java

Today we talked about `Overriding and Shadowing` in Java and in one of the slides (i've attached it below) we were told to pay close attention to the last 3 lines and make sure we understand what's going on. I'm not sure i do though so i'd like some help or explanation. My understanding is that, since `b` was explicitly casted to a `B` object from a `D` object, calling `b.i` accesses the current class's `i` member field which in this case would be the B class's with a value of 6. But when it has to call the `f()` method which was overriden by D from B, the compiler decided that it should call D's implementation of the f() method because the object was originally a D object(?). I'm really not sure if i've understand this thing right so i'd appreciate your feedback.

P.S: Since both the `superclass` and the `subclass` have a variable with the same name and type (`i`) but without conflict, isn't that `shadowing`?

[image: slide]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case 1:

```
System.out.println(b.i);
```

This is **variable hiding** - "When an instance variable in a subclass has the same name as an instance variable in a super class, then the instance variable is chosen from the reference type."

In your situation, d was cast to B so the instance variable from B is displayed.

Case 2:

```
System.out.println(b.f());
```

This is **method overriding** - "(...) overridden methods completely replace the inherited methods, so when we try to access the method from a parent's reference by holding a child's object, the method from the child class gets called."

More can be found here: https://dzone.com/articles/variable-shadowing-and-hiding-in-java